# JavaScript `switch` comparing objects does not work as expected

Tags: javascript

Please have a look at my code:

```
const foo = {
   value: new String("ABC")
}

const bar = {
  value: new String("XYZ")
}

const baz = {
  value: foo.value
}

switch (baz.value) {
  case foo.value: {
    console.log("ABC")
  }
  case bar.value: {
    console.log("XYZ")
 }
}
```

expected: `ABC`
current: `ABC` `XYZ`

`bar.value` contains another object then `foo.value`
`foo.value === bar.value` returns false
so how does it work then?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `break` before a new `case`, unless you want the equal result for both. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: You forget to break after your case. In switch statements, it will continue executing other cases unless you break at the end of each case.

Comment: I do not want to `break`, my example should not pass the second `case` anyway. But it does and I do not understand why.

Comment: Reads like you have to read and understand how `switch` works in javascript. Check my link in the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place break instructions at the end of each case in the switch. That should do the job.

Comment: I do not want to `break`, my example should not pass the second `case` anyway. But it does and I do not understand why.

Comment: If you don't place a break after each case even if the values are OR are not equal it will also execute the code from the cases where the values do not match with the one given as a parameter to the switch.

Here is a very short JS example:
`switch(1) {
    case 1: {   
        console.log(1);
    }
    case 2: {
        console.log(2);
    }
}`
If you test this you will see that it will print both 1 and 2.
On the other hand if you place the breaks in the above example you will see that it only prints 1.

Answer (score 1):

As Lain said, the `break` is missing. In this case, the code operates the first case then goes two the second.

```
switch (baz.value) {
  case foo.value: {
    console.log("ABC")
    break

  }
  case bar.value: {
    console.log("XYZ")
    break
 } 
}
```

Comment: I do not want to `break`, my example should not pass the second `case` anyway. But it does and I do not understand why.